# MS Teams Bot continues to display commands when I have removed them

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have a Node.Js bot written using the MS BotFramework. I have tested it locally and deployed it to Azure, i can use it in Web Chat and i can use it in Teams after i install a manifest generated by the Teams App Studio. However, here is my problem:
[Teams Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqmw9.png)

I have removed the "Commands" section from my app manifest, but the continue to show up when i reinstall the app in Teams.

Here is my manifest:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.7/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.7",
    "version": "1",
    "showLoadingIndicator": true,
    "id": "**<ID Omitted>**",
    "packageName": "botteamsadoption",
    "developer": {
        "name": "DPR Construction",
        "websiteUrl": "https://dprprod.sharepoint.com/sites/toolbox/Pages/Welcome.aspx",
        "privacyUrl": "https://dprprod.sharepoint.com/sites/toolbox/hr/Pages/HomePage.aspx",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://dprprod.sharepoint.com/sites/toolbox/hr/Pages/HomePage.aspx"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "ITService",
        "full": "ITService ChatBot"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Chat Bot for IT Related Issues",
        "full": "This is the new Chat solution for ITService. Use this to speak directly to the IT Service Desk or obtain information about known issues."
    },
    "accentColor": "#FEAE25",


    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "**<ID Omitted>**",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "groupchat",
                "personal"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": true,
            "isNotificationOnly": false
        }
    ],


    "composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "<**ID Omitted**",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "commands": []
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": []
}
```

Any ideas as to how i can get these to stop displaying? I have already created a new manifest...but what i suspect the issue is is -- i am having to use the same Azure app ID for my Bot. MS Support has suggested that i remove my Azure app registration and create a new one, redeploy my code and make a new manifest. This is not possible for me at the moment and i am hoping for another suggestion.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's using the latest manifest? I assume you've checked obvious things, like that you're removing the app entirely in App Studio, and then re-adding it by uploading this manifest, or something similar? If so, another suggestion is to 'up' the version, like make it 1.0.1 instead of 1. Interestingly, your version looks a bit simple ("1"). It should be at least "1.0.0"

Comment: is your issue resolved?